Number of functions with at least two consecutive values equal
Apologies for the poor title.
Let $N$ and $k$ be fixed. We can take $N\geq 6$ and $k\geq 5$ but I don't think this is important.
Where $[N]=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ and similar for $[k]$, consider the set of functions $[k]\to [N]$. I believer there are $N^k$ such functions.
I am interested in the number of these functions such that there exists (at least one)  $n\in[k]$ such that $f(n)=f(n+1)$ (to include $f(k)=f(1)$).
So for example, $g=\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,4),(4,2),(5,4)\}$ would not be in this subset but $f=\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,4)\}$.
I am getting, roughly, $N^k-N(N-1)^{k-2}(N-2)$ but this isn't right. This is got by taking all the functions that don't have two consecutive values equal - saying $N$ choices for $f(1)$ and then each of the next $k-2$ choices $f(n)$ for $2\leq n\leq N-1$ have to avoid $f(n-1)$ but then $f(k)$ must avoid $f(k-1)$ and $f(1)$... but this is incorrect in the case $f(k-1)=f(1)$... so I try and correct but taking two cases, $f(1)=f(k-1)$ and $f(1)\neq f(k-1)$, but then I get into the same trouble again if $f(k-1)=f(k-3)$, etc.

$(1,3)$ meaning $1$ getting mapped to $3$?

@Zima yes......

The answer is $(N-1)^k+(-1)^k(N-1)$. This question has a proof in terms of chromatic polynomials, and a proof using the principle of inclusion exclusion. This other question has a combinatorial proof.

@MikeEarnest I assume you mean $N^k$ minus this? If so, thank you.
